# Events showing up in Google home app but not in pub/sub messages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, nest-device-access

As title states I am seeing events for my wired nest camera in the Google Home app, but no messages are being sent to pub/sub from it.

Messages from my thermostat & doorbell all send fine, also the camera was sending messages previously, but now all of a sudden it stopped sending them, nothing changed it just stopped sending pub/sub messages.

I have restarted the camera several times, I am struggling to troubleshoot this as there's not much help by the way of Googles docs.

What could've caused it to stop delivering messages? I checked connectivity etc and all is fine, and it works perfectly in the Google home app.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: @Ted hmm, hopefully it's a downtime issue and they're working on it then.

Comment: Looks like Google resolved the issue with the first generation cameras, but my second generation camera still does not fire any events.

Comment: @Ted yes I am concerned with the issues with events I've been experiencing as of late, would be nice to have some correspondence from Google regarding this, but their documentation/support for developers with the Nest devices is not exactly what you'd expect from google.

Comment: @Ted this should have been resolved for all users now - are you still not seeing events?

Comment: @Ethan: Still nothing from the second gen cameras.

Comment: Can you provide the details regarding camera model, account email, timestamp, and what events were missing ? This will help us in investigating the issue.